# Interpreting Jenkins failure with ruby and rake

Tags: ruby, jenkins, rake

I am just trying to get a proof of concept of Jenkins working on my local machine.  All I want to see happen is Jenkins execute a task in a rakefile.  Here is the error I am getting.

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\thursday test\workspace
[workspace] $ C:\Ruby193\bin\rake.bat --rakefile C:\Users\zreichert\workspace\FalconQA\testCases\rakefile.rb FAL001
'"ruby.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Build step 'Invoke Rake' marked build as failure
```

I have ruby 1.93, jenkins 1.485, ruby plugin 1.2, rake plugin 1.7.7

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is ruby in your path?   I'm not so familiar with Jenkins on Windows, but in Linux if your environment isn't set up for the default user, say jenkins, then things will bomb out.